# What is the rereduce parameter in CouchDB's reduce function for?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, mapreduce

As I understand the reduce function takes all the values of a particular key and we can write code to perform some kind of action on those values.
I do not understand what is the use of the rereduce parameter. Can somebody explain with an example?

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_vs_rereduce gives you an good overview. Due to performance optimations, the reduce function may be called on two levels:

- to reduce a block
- to reduce results of the first step

In the second level, the parameter `rereduce` is `true`. For an example see http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions#A_sum. In the first step the length of the block (`values`) is returned, on the rereduce level these lengths must be summed up.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Can a set of data be sent to the reduce function more than 2 times(2 levels) ? That is it is reduced, rereduced and again rereduced?

Comment: So as a contrived example, say you had a list of String numbers and your reduction wanted to simply sum them all. The first "level" would operate on keys and the (string) values themselves, converting them to numbers and sum them. The second "level" (rereduce == true) would work on the results of the first level (numbers), and simply sum them without needing to parse any strings.

Comment: Thanks @aaaidan . Just one more clarification. Why is the following function inefficient : var rv = {};
for (i in values) {
    var value = values[i];
    for (k in value) {
        rv[k] = (rv[k] || 0) + value[k];
    }
}
return rv; I am taking this from the following link - http://blog.mudynamics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/icouch.html - Unique cameras for a user attempt #1

Comment: Code doesn't fit well in comments. Perhaps ask this in another question?

Answer (score -1):

There's an explanation of the rereduce parameter [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions).

Quote: paraphrased. More info at the link.

> Here is an example of a reduce function:
>
> ```
> function (key, values, rereduce) {
>     return sum(values); 
> }
> ```
>
> Reduce functions must handle two cases, when rereduce is true and when it is false.

Comment: This is not a good answer because it doesn't explain why that example allows for rereduce true. It is misleading since it doesn't say what the input keys and values are in each case

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ZachSmith